# array_rand wihout repeating in php

Tags: php, text, textcolor

I'm working with my code that will allow the user to input a word and each letter of the word will give a meaning.

Example: User inputted a text "APPLE".
Output:

```
A - arc
P - priest
P - president
L - lion
E - escape
```

The meaning of every letter will be in array..

I already have my code here but the meaning are repeated.

Example:

```
A -  **Arrow**
L -  Love
A - **Arrow**
S - Soul
```

Here's my code

```
<?php
$chars = str_split("APPLE");
foreach($chars as $char){
    if (substr($char, 0, 1) === 'A')
    {
    $meaning = array("Angel","Ancient","Arrow");
    echo $meaning[array_rand($meaning)];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could unset it temporarily inside the loop so that you won't get dups. Example:

```
$chars = str_split("APPLE");
$words = array(
    // its up to you what words you want to map
    'A' => array("Angel","Ancient","Arrow"),
    'E' => array('Elephat', 'Eardrum'),
    'L' => array('Level', 'Laravel', 'Love'),
    'S' => array('Sweet', 'Spicy', 'Savy'),
    'P' => array('Powerful', 'Predictable', 'Pass', 'piss')
);

foreach($chars as $char){
    $random_key = array_rand($words[$char]); // get random key
    $key = $words[$char][$random_key]; // get the word
    unset($words[$char][$random_key]); // unset it so that it will never be repeated
    echo "$char - $key <br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save a "cache" array of previously used terms. Example:

```
<?php
$chars = str_split("APPLE");
$used_terms = array();
foreach($chars as $char){
    if (substr($char, 0, 1) === 'A') {
        $meaning = array("Angel","Ancient","Arrow");
        do {
            $term = $meaning[array_rand($meaning)];
        } while (in_array($term, $used_terms));
        $used_terms[] = $term;

        echo $term;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: My bad, it should be a do-while loop. Updated.

Comment: Though, the unset method by @Ghost is more efficient :)